# How can this loop be vectorized?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array that looks like:

```
array([[ -1. , 184. ,   0.5],
       [ -1. , 174. ,   1.0],
       [ -1. , 104. ,   0.5],
       [  1. ,  44. ,   0.5],
       [  1. ,  28. ,   0.5],
       [  1. ,  70. ,   0.5],
       [ -1. ,  34. ,   0.5],
       ...,
       [  1. ,  10. ,   0.5],
       [  1. ,  12. ,   0.5],
       [  1. ,  86. ,   1.0],
       [ -1. ,  36. ,   0.5],
       [  1. ,   2. ,   0.5],
       [ -1. ,  32. ,   1.5],
       [  1. ,  10. ,   0.5]])
```

And I have a function to find the indices of the array that meet the condition listed in the for loop:

```
def loop(array):
    n_init = 100
    a = np.dot(array[:n_init, 0], array[:n_init, 1])
    b = np.sum(array[:n_init, 2])
    loc_start = n_init
    idx = []
    lst_a, lst_b = [], []
    lst_a.append(a)
    lst_b.append(b)
    for step in range(n_init + 1, array.shape[0]):
        mean_a = np.mean(lst_a)
        mean_b = np.mean(lst_b)
        _a = np.dot(array[loc_start:step, 0], array[loc_start:step, 1])
        _b = np.sum(array[loc_start:step, 2])
        if np.abs(_a) * _b >= np.abs(mean_a) * mean_b:
            loc_start = step
            lst_a.append(_a)
            lst_b.append(_b)
            idx.append(step)
    return idx
```

The function firstly initializes n_init rows in order to calculate 2 scalars a and b which are appended to the lists lst_a and lst_b that are used in the for loop later.

In the loop, starting from the entry right after the n_init row, mean values of lst_a and lst_b, and also the values of _a (dot operation of column 0 and 1 from last idx to current step) and _b (sum of column 2 from last idx to current step) are computed.

A row number i.e. index appended to idx, is found when the absolute value of _a multiplied by _b is greater than or equal to the absolute value of the mean of the lst_a multiplied by the mean value of lst_b, and as the condition is met, the current _a and _b are appended to lst_a and lst_b respectively. The entire loop ends when step reaches the length of the array.

Because the array has millions of rows, it takes a very long time to finish. Can this process be vectorized and how?

Comment: can you explain what your function does?

Comment: @ Akshay Nevrekar What the function does has been added, thanks

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't clear enough but I was expecting you to provide the logic behind your function with input and expected output(not line to line explanation). You will get better response if you provide that. [How to ask question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're building up a state (`lst_a` and `lst_b`) and using it to check whether a new entry should belong to the state or not. As such, I believe it cannot be completely vectorized.

Something you can try to speed it up is to use incremental computation (actually, the inverse of vectorization, if you will).

For instance `mean_a` and `mean_b` are currently recomputed at each step, even if it didn't change and, when it changes, you could just update it instead of fully recompute it.

Also `_a` and `_b` could be updated instead of recomputed. It would save the array slices and a few computation (might not be worth it if `loc_start` is not too far away`).
Try it out and compare.

Answer (score 0):

You can't vectorize it (as you are populating lists iteratively and using them in the calculation), but you can do a lot of calculation vectorized up front. Maybe.

```
def loop(array):
    loc_start = 100
    A = np.cumsum(array[:, 0] * array[:, 1])
    B = np.cumsum(array[:, 2])
    a, b = A[loc_start], B[loc_start]
    idx = []
    lst_a, lst_b = [a], [b]
    thr = np.abs(a)/ b
    for step in range(n_init + 1, array.shape[0]):
        _a = A[step] - a
        _b = B[step] - b
        if np.abs(_a) * _b >= thr:
            loc_start = step
            a, b = a_, b_
            lst_a.append(a)
            lst_b.append(b)
            thr = np.abs(np.mean(lst_a)) / np.mean(lst_b)
            idx.append(step)
    return idx
```

As long as your `cumsum` arrays don't overflow (check the values of `A[-1]` and `B[-1]` to see), this should be a lot faster.